# React native vector icons - dynamic type

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I'm using different types of react native vector icons - Material and FontAwesome depending on availability of a particular icon. I wanted to create a common component that wraps usage of the icons across the app. So far I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import {theme} from "../../../styles/style";

/**
 * Common reusable icon component
 * @param props
 * @returns {*}
 */
const icon = (props) => {
    return (
        <Icon
            size={theme.SIZE_ICON}
            color={theme.BACKGROUND_ICON_COLOR}
            {...props}
            style={props.style}/>
    );
};

export default icon;
```

Which works only for FontAwesome, how can I make it dynamic based on e.g. prop parameter so I can use Material icons when I need to? Note: I wouldn't like to create separate components for each type e.g. IconMaterial, IconFontAwesome etc. I want the name of the component to be Icon regardless of type. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a prop called `iconFamily` to your icon component:

Inside your Icon Component you are importing all the Fonts you want to use, e.g.:

```
import IconFA from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import IconMA from "react-native-vector-icons/Material";
```

Then inside Icon's render function:

```
  const Icon = (props) => {

  renderIcon = () => {
    if (props.iconFamily == "FA") {
      return (
        <IconFA
        size={23}
        {...props}
        style={props.style}/>
      );
   } 
   if (props.iconFamily == "MA") {
      return (
        <IconMA
        size={23}
        {...props}
        style={props.style}/>
      );
   }
  }
  return (
      renderIcon()
  )
}
```

An when you are using your custom icon component you just have to specify the iconFamily prop:

```
 <Icon iconFamily="FA" name="home" color="green" /> 
 <Icon iconFamily="MA" name="code" color="red" />
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Complete Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/humiliated-hummus

Answer (score 2):

I always liked doing it that way.
~/components/VectorIcons.js

```js
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo'
import EvilIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather'
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
import FontAwesome5Pro from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5Pro'
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto'
import Foundation from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import Octicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons'
import SimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons'
import Zocial from 'react-native-vector-icons/Zocial'


const VectorIcon = {
  AntDesign,
  Entypo,
  EvilIcons,
  Feather,
  FontAwesome,
  FontAwesome5,
  FontAwesome5Pro,
  Fontisto,
  Foundation,
  Ionicons,
  MaterialCommunityIcons,
  MaterialIcons,
  Octicons,
  SimpleLineIcons,
  Zocial,
}

export default VectorIcon
```

To use in any jsx
~/pages/Home/index.jsx

```js
import VectorIcon from '../../components/VectorIcon'

return (
  <>
   // ...
   <VectorIcon.AntDesign name="home" />
   <VectorIcon.Fontisto name="clock-outline" />
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Icon Component, and maybe you can get an idea from this.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Ionicons,
  AntDesign,
  Entypo,
  EvilIcons,
  Feather,
  FontAwesome,
  FontAwesome5,
  Fontisto,
  Foundation,
  MaterialCommunityIcons,
  MaterialIcons,
  Octicons,
  SimpleLineIcons,
  Zocial,
} from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Icon= ({ family, name, ...props }) => {
  let Family;

  switch (family) {
    case "AntDesign":
      Family = AntDesign;
      break;
    case "Entypo":
      Family = Entypo;
      break;
    case "EvilIcons":
      Family = EvilIcons;
      break;
    case "Feather":
      Family = Feather;
      break;
    case "FontAwesome":
      Family = FontAwesome;
      break;
    case "FontAwesome5":
      Family = FontAwesome5;
      break;
    case "Fontisto":
      Family = Fontisto;
      break;
    case "Foundation":
      Family = Foundation;
      break;
    case "Ionicons":
      Family = Ionicons;
      break;
    case "MaterialCommunityIcons":
      Family = MaterialCommunityIcons;
      break;
    case "MaterialIcons":
      Family = MaterialIcons;
      break;
    case "Octicons":
      Family = Octicons;
      break;
    case "SimpleLineIcons":
      Family = SimpleLineIcons;
      break;
    case "Zocial":
      Family = Zocial;
      break;
    default:
      Family = Ionicons;
  }

  return (
    <Family
      name={name ? name : "help-outline"}
      color={"#000"}
      size={20}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

And to use it you can do this.

```js
<Icon
    family="Ionicons"
    name="add-outline"
    color={"#333"}
    size={30}
/>
```

I add the default family and name to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-dynamic-vector-icons`

https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-dynamic-vector-icons

```
import Icon, { IconType } from "react-native-dynamic-vector-icons";

<Icon
  name="github"
  type={IconType.AntDesign}
  size={30}
  color="purple"
  onPress={() => {}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**i Found a great solution**
i make a seperate component and in the component i just pass iconLibrary name and icon name and icon color as a props

```js
import {View} from 'react-native';
import React, {FC} from 'react';
//here is the import icon libraries
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import EvilIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';
import Foundation from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Octicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
import Zocial from 'react-native-vector-icons/Zocial';
import SimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

interface myIcon {
  iconLibrary: string;
  iconName: string;
  iconColor: string;
}

const VectorIcon: FC<myIcon> = ({iconLibrary, iconName, iconColor}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {iconLibrary === 'AntDesign' && (
        <AntDesign name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'Entypo' && (
        <Entypo name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'EvilIcons' && (
        <EvilIcons name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'Feather' && (
        <Feather name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'FontAwesome' && (
        <FontAwesome name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'FontAwesome5' && (
        <FontAwesome5 name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'Fontisto' && (
        <Fontisto name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'Foundation' && (
        <Foundation name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'Ionicons' && (
        <Ionicons name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'MaterialIcons' && (
        <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'MaterialCommunityIcons' && (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'Octicons' && (
        <Octicons name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'Zocial' && (
        <Zocial name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}

      {iconLibrary === 'SimpleLineIcons' && (
        <SimpleLineIcons name={iconName} size={20} color={iconColor} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default VectorIcon;
```

**where we want to use**

```js
 <VectorIcon
          iconColor={iconColor}
          iconLibrary={iconLibrary}
          iconName={iconName}
  />
```